# Из js в php

Tags: php

Есть вот такой js код:

```
function chLvl(exp){var a=90;var b=10;exp+=a;return exp<a?0:(-1*(2*a-b)+Math.sqrt((2*a-b)*(2*a-b)-4*b*(-2*exp)))/(2*b);}
```

Попытался сделать его в php, но значения получаю разные что не так ?

```
$crexp = $crexp.'90';
$lv = floor((-1*(2*90-10)+sqrt((2*90-10)*(2*90-10)-4*90*(-2*$crexp)))/(2*10));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function chLvl($exp) {
    $a = 90;
    $b = 10;
    $exp += $a;
    return ($exp < $a) ? 0 : ((-1*(2*$a-$b)+sqrt((2*$a-$b)*(2*$a-$b)-4*$b*(-2*$exp)))/(2*$b));
}
echo chLvl(100);
```

Удачи.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть `$crexp = $crexp.'+90';` а то вы к числу приписываете еще `90`.